# How to implement long press on screen in android?

Tags: android, long-press

I have used tablelayout within the scrollview. Now I want to use long press on the screen(i.e on long pressing anywhere on the screen I want to do some actions).

Please if anybody knows help me out.

Comment: Maybe by using an [onLongClick listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) on your parent Layout?

Answer (score 2):

In your TableLayout apply listener to your Root layout(Parent layout)

```
TableLayout parentLayout;
parentLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout):
parentLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: within the onLongClick I have implemented onCreateContextMenu() and onContextItemSelected() methods to provide context menu. I don't know whether I am doing right or not.Please help me out in this regard.

Comment: Dont implement those methods inside longclick.. implement out side.

Comment: But I want to provide context menu upon long click...Do you mean implementing outside and calling the same method within the onLongClick()?

Comment: You can register inside button long click   registerForContextMenu( v );  and implement those out context menu methods out side

Comment: But Context Menu replaced by Contextual actionbar: follow this link: http://java.dzone.com/articles/contextual-action-bar-cab

Comment: Sorry I am new to android,can u just brief out please??

Comment: thank you for ur quick response ...I gone through the link and trying to implement the same in my project